# If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are continuous random variables from a $U(0,10)$ distribution, then what is the probability density function of $X_1 + X_2$?

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution, uniform-distribution, density-function

Suppose that  $X_1, X_2 \sim U(0,10)$ are continuous random variables. How would I derive the probability density function of $X_1 + X_2$? Clearly we have
$$
f_{X_1}(x) = f_{X_2} = 0.1
$$
and so 
$$
f_{X_1+X_2}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1}(s) \hspace{1mm} f_{X_2}(x-s) \hspace{2mm} ds
$$
(if anyone knows what this rule is called, if it has a name, please let me know).

Now, since $f_{X_1}(x) = 0.1$ if $0 \leq x \leq 10$ and is $0$ otherwise, this integral can be simplified to
$$
f_{X_1+X_2}(x) = 0.1 \int_0^{10} f_{X_2}(x-s) \hspace{2mm} ds
$$

This is where I struggle to see what should happen next. Would anyone be able to help me to understand how to proceed from here?

Cheers.

Comment: See here: <https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Book%3A_Introductory_Probability_(Grinstead_and_Snell)/07%3A_Sums_of_Random_Variables/7.02%3A_Sums_of_Continuous_Random_Variables>

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about "convolution," which is only applicable when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. In your final integral I observe that $f_{X_2}(x-s)$ is only nonzero if $x-s \in [0,10]$, that is, $0\leq x-s \leq 10$.

Comment: What you need to do now is to calculate the integral of a piecewise function - there's no stochastics involved at this point anymore. I.e. define $$ f(x):= f_{X_2}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &, x<0\\ 0.1 &,x\in [0,10]\\ 0 &, x>10\end{cases}$$ and calculate $\int_0^{10} f(x-s)ds$

Comment: Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y=X_1+X_2$

$f_Y(y)=0.1 \int_0^{10} f_{X_2}(y-s) ds$

we need to clarify the area $$0<y<20 \, \ 0<s<10 \, \ 0<y-s<10$$

[image]

Split in two situation $y<10$ and $10<y<20$
\begin{eqnarray}
f_Y(y)&=&\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
0.1 \int_0^{y} f_{X_2}(y-s) ds  &  y\leq 10  \\
0.1 \int_{y-10}^{10} f_{X_2}(y-s) ds  &   10<y<20 \\
0 & O.W
\end{array}
\right.
\\
&=&\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
0.1 \int_0^{y} 0.1 ds  &  y\leq 10  \\
0.1 \int_{y-10}^{10} 0.1 ds  &   10<y<20 \\
0 & O.W
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}